# New CentOS 8 Install Crashing

Tags: centos, freeze, crash, dmesg

So I just installed CentOS 8 and I keep having random freezes/crashes. I have tried looking at my `/var/log/messages` but I can't find anything of use to it. The crashes happen inconsistently and I can't replicate it by doing a certain process. When I look at my dmesg, there are certain things that I see regularly but I'm not sure what the actual issue is and how to resolve it, even after Google and Stack Exchange searches. Here's the dump of my dmesg so if there is anything I should research deeper please let me know or if there's somewhere else I should look. One thing I should mention is that in the past dmesg dumps I've seen PulseAudio having trouble but I'm not sure if that is of importance. I can find that and copy that here if it may be useful.

````
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Started /run/user/995 mount wrapper.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 995.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 995...
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Started Session 72 of user pcp.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Reached target Paths.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Listening on Sound System.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Listening on Multimedia System.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Reached target Timers.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Reached target Sockets.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Reached target Basic System.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 995.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Starting Sound Service...
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@995.service: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 995...
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Stopped Sound Service.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Closed Multimedia System.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Closed Sound System.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[31542]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@995.service: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 995.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@995.service: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 995.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping /run/user/995 mount wrapper...
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped /run/user/995 mount wrapper.
Oct 12 18:58:01 localhost rtkit-daemon[931]: Warning: PolicyKit call failed: Unix process subject does not have uid set
Oct 12 18:58:02 localhost dnf[31531]: CentOS-8 - AppStream                            1.9 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:02
Oct 12 18:58:04 localhost dnf[31531]: CentOS-8 - Base                                 1.8 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:02
Oct 12 18:58:06 localhost dnf[31531]: CentOS-8 - Extras                               688  B/s | 1.5 kB     00:02
Oct 12 18:58:07 localhost dnf[31531]: Metadata cache created.
Oct 12 18:58:07 localhost systemd[1]: Started dnf makecache.
Oct 12 19:00:00 localhost systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...
Oct 12 19:00:00 localhost systemd[1]: Started system activity accounting tool.```
````

Comment: can you describe a bit these crashes or freezes? Did you use `journalctl` to check the logs systematically? (your paste is a good start). I have lots of ideas, but I can't really guide you. With random crashes you'd need some kernel dump ("postmortem"), for freezes rather system diagnostic (top, ps, ... ). And observations. Modules are always a suspect I think. But how to track that down?

Comment: It's hard to describe because it happens at random times. On the GUI, it literally just freezes and using Pulseway (Remote Management Software), it shows it as offline/shutdown. Unfortunately journalctl only shows the last boot, so after the crash. I do see Pulseway in red even during the current session though but nothing stands out other than that. It's got a "failed to start service" with "core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied". I've tried to look at as many logs as I can but it just shows a sudden stop instead of a kernel dump or other. I'll keep looking at thosetho

Comment: In my modprobe.d directory I only have firewalld, lockd, truescale, vhost, kvm, mlx4, and tuned. Like I said, it's a fresh install with only a few things installed, which is the troubling part. I just thought that maybe it's a hardware issue so I'm going to start running some stress tests

Comment: "Unfortunately journalctl only shows the last boot, so after the crash..." OK but 1) you could maybe find something shortly before...the final lines 2) systemd/journalctl have lots of additional features, exactly for that unfortunate situation you are in. You know about socalled kernel panic? How it looks? A "raw" kernal panic on the console almost always gives a hint. Stress tests: one possibility. I think it is called "trying to reproduce".